# WebKit how do I get the DOM when an element is clicked in a WebView?

Tags: objective-c, webview, webkit

Is there any way to respond to clicking on elements within a `WebView` and return the associated HTML for the given element?

For example, is there any way to set up a handler or delegate that will return me the `<tr/>` DOM element in when a given `<tr>` is clicked?

I'm using WebKit on OS X.